# How to require Docker Certified images on Gitlab?

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerhub

Gitlab lets you use any image on Docker Hub but how can I restrict to Docker Certified images?  The advice I read in [Docker Reference Architecture: Building a Docker Secure Supply Chain](https://success.docker.com/article/secure-supply-chain) implies that this is something I do (manually) when I look for an image:

> Picking the right images from Docker Hub is critical. Start with
> Certified Images, then move on to official images. Lastly, consider
> community images. Only use community images that are an automated
> build. This helps ensure that they are updated in a timely fashion.
> Verification of the freshness of the image is important as well.

...

> When searching Docker Hub for images, make sure to check the Docker Certified checkbox.

But can I set up Gitlab to ensure that the images I'm using are Certified Images?  For example, suppose an image I chose one day *loses* its certification?  I would want to be notified of the vulnerability automatically, let's say at build time or even more proactively.

Comment: There is https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ImageSearch but that does not provide whether the image is certified...